# Вернуть из функции два значения кортежем (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь вернуть из метода значения двух переменных кортежем:

```
public int Fun()
{
    //(int, int) tuple = (3, 5);`
    var tuple = (3, 5);
    return tuple;
}

public void OnMouseEnter()
{
    print(Fun());
}
```

Подскажите, в чем я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: `public int` - не смущает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибаетесь в типе возврата, возвращая одно `int`-овое число:

```
public int Fun() { ... }
```

Должен быть кортеж:

```
public (int, int) Fun() { ... }
```

Comment: да, ошибка указывала именно на возврат одного int

Answer (score 2):

Наверное должно быть так:

```
public Tuple<int, int> Fun()
{
     // ...
     return tuple;
}
```

либо так

```
public (int foo, int bar) Fun()
{
    return (3, 5);
}
```

и

```
public (int, int) Fun()
{
    return (3, 5);
}
```

Чтобы возвращать именно кортеж, а не просто целое число

Comment: Вас так же благодарю за развернутый ответ...